# Share a maven assembly descriptor with resources in it

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I would like to create an assembly descriptor defining how my applications are uploaded on Nexus and in particular I would like those final packages to include a couple of startup scripts handy to run applications on different platforms.  Untill now I have always copied the assembly descritor and the startup template scripts from project to project, but now I would like to find a clever solution for the problem.

In the documentation page of the maven-assembly-plugin I found an [example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/sharing-descriptors.html) showing how to share descriptors across multiple projects;  unfortunately it does not cover the case where one wants to include a *common* resource in the the distribution package but and after a couple of experiments I came to the conclusion it is impossible to do that:  to include a resource in the distribution file one has to specify the *path* of the resource (apparently it is not possible to link a resource contained within a jar).

Additional solutions I have found so far try to use the **ant** or **dependency** plugins to unpack the jar containing the the assembly descritor and the script templates inside the build folder before packaging the application.

Even if I can stick with the the solutions of the last paragraph, I am wondering if there is a clearer way to achieve that:  do I really need to use additional plugins for such a task?

Comment: Scripts to run an application can be generated by using [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) apart from that the generated scripts having a configuration folder (./etc) which can contain configuration files etc.

Comment: I don't think switching to appsembler-mave-plugin would actually solve my problems:  I have packaging rules I have to follow and don't know if that plugin will actually allow me to be compliant.